# Solving 5 differential equations numerically, Method suggestions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have these 5 equations:
\begin{align}
\dot\psi&=\frac{p_\psi}{2r} -\frac{\sin(\psi)}{r} \\
\dot r&=\cos(\psi) \\
\dot h&=\sin(\psi) \\
\dot p_\psi&=\left(\frac{p_\psi}{r} -p_h\right)\cos(\psi)+\left(\frac{2\sigma r}{a^2} +p_r\right)\sin(\psi) \\
\dot p_r&=\frac{p_\psi}{r}\left(\frac{p_\psi}{4r} -\frac{\sin(\psi)}{r}\right)+\frac{2\sigma}{a^2}\big(1-\cos(\psi)\big) \\
\end{align}

Where $ \psi , h, r, p_\psi, p_r$ are functions of $s$.
with five boundary conditions at $s=0$ 
$$r(0),h(0),\psi(0),p_\psi(0),p_r(0)$$

I already can solve them using software like Mathematica and Maple, but I want to write a code to solve them numerically, and I don't know which method can be used. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try Runge-Kutta?

Comment: Have you a reason to suspect that some method will not work? Have you tried some order 2 Runge-Kutta methods or RK4? Were the results consistent with physical expectations?

Comment: @moo no i didnt try.

Comment: @LutzL no i dont have, and didnt try. will it work since the equations are coupled?

Comment: You will need to use the vectorized versions of the methods, but they all should work and give results within their error orders. Methods of the same order usually differ by some small factor in the error.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to solve it with RK4 and integrate the lagrangian with Trapezoidal rule.

Comment: @LutzL lets say s is between [0,10] but for an initial condition value there will be solution till s somewhere in that interval, will RK4 be viable?

Comment: Are you asking about a solution that moves to infinity in finite time?

Comment: Any integral over the solution can be implemented as an additional component of the state vector whose derivative is the integrand. Then you get the same error order as the original solution.

Comment: There is a value $w$ which goes into two boundary conditions. For $w=-1.185$ then the equations are solvable over the interval [0:10] but for $w=-3$ then the equations are solvable over the interval [0:2.4]. So using RK4 with wrong value of $w$ there will be no answer, is there another way other than starting from small interval and change $w$ till we get larger interval and so on till arrive to the desired interval?